# Can not find result from a search list for one store

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

I am new to SharePoint, I have a list of stores into a mall, and one user can, successfully find a store, after performing a search and another one is not finding using the same search term.

One thing I noticed is that the date is 1900.

What can possibly interfering into the search?

Comment: Is there any SQL query that shows if the store can be searchable in the list for people from one group ? and not searchable for another group ?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the problematic user has the same permissions as the successful user. Ensure that they have at least Read permission on the content they are searching for.